# Microsoft Project Plan convert to PDF C#

Tags: c#, ms-project

I want to convert a Microsoft Project Plan File to PDF with the Office DLL.
Can any one provide me the sample code?

I dont want to use any third party DLLs. I want to do this with using MS Office 2010 DLL.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Publisher.Document.SaveAs try this out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in API that convert MPP to PDF. Anyway, [Document.SaveAs Method (Publisher)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff940221.aspx) allows you save it into many file formats includes HTML and RTF.

Comment: its possible i did that successfully you can download the sample program from given link

https://skydrive.live.com/?lc=24841#cid=2F22272220E37707&id=2F22272220E37707%21103

program name=ConvertExcel2PDF